Time complexity of bisect on ordered dict?
Given this code snippet, can anyone tell me the time complexity?
import collections
a = collections.OrderedDict()
for i in range(100):
    a[i] = i

import bisect
ind = bisect.bisect_left(a.keys(), 45.3)

Initially it may appear O(log(n)). However, ordered dict does not implement a BST. So in order to copy the keys over to some array/list in order for bisect to use, it would take O(n) time right?

There's no copy involved; OrderedDict.keys() doesn't create a new list, it returns a list-like object exposing the contents of the dict itself directly.

The call to bisect_left() gets an error because a.keys() is not a sequence that supports indexing. You have to convert it to a list first. That's O(n) and then the bisection is O(log n)

Did you check your code actually runs?

as an aside, what motivated you to use collections.OrderedDict? Are you aware that dict objects maintain insertion order already?

@Barmar Got it thanks. I got this code from somewhere else

@juanpa.arrivillaga why does the insertion order matter?

@JobHunter69 what do you mean what does it matter? That's what ordered dict does. I think you may incorrectly believe that OrderedDict maintains a sorted order. It doesn't, it simply maintains insertion order. The use cases for this type have narrowed considerably since dict became ordered. Note, the code you have here may have worked in Python 2.7, where .keys() does return a list

If you are trying to use a sorted dict (or list) implementation you should use the sortedcontainers library.

@juanpa.arrivillaga It does work in Python 2, and probably was written for it.
